# using asp.net dll in classic asp

Tags: asp.net, asp-classic, com, com+

I've followed this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19535/NET-COM-Interop-Component-with-Classic-ASP-Part-I & http://bruceburge.com/2009/06/11/sharing-net-libary-dlls-between-asp-classic-and-aspnet/ to use `asp.net` dll in classic asp.

Step 7 listed in first URL didn't work me hence I followed steps given in second URL to to create installation. It works & can see URL in GAC. Unfortunately, it is not working in classic asp.

I tried `"regsvcs"` at command prompt but didn't work. have developed using C#

Anybody knows what I'm missing?

Update: I could see component under Component Services. I don't see method name under Interfaces & creating object of component is not working. am getting this error:

```
Expected end of statement on line:
set obj= server.CreateObject("my_dll_New.Class1");
```

Comment: What language is that meant to be? If it's VB, then remove the `;` at the end of the line.